# copy files and folders from local to a mapped network drive for backup

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've written a simple script that enables me to copy files and folders from my NAS to my external hard disk. My NAS drive is mapped to a network drive Z: and my external hard disk is to drive E:.

It didn't like it by saying "A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist".

Then, I ran "Test-Path Y:" and it came back "False".

So I'm not sure why it didn't recognize the Y drive when I can see it physically listed under "Computer" in windows explorer. It shows all the folders under that drive when clicking it.

I'm not sure what I missed out here.

Thank you

Comment: You mention drive `E:` and the error: *"A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist"*, and then you introduce drive `Y:` , so not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry Kev, it's a typo. I was meant to write "Test-Path Z:" and it came back "False". Thank you